# Remove everything but characters from a string?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently starting with ruby, and within the homework of my course it is asked to manipulate strings, which raises a question.

Given a string link this:

```
I'm the janitor, that's what I am!
```

Task is to remove everything but the characters from the string so that the result is

```
IamthejanitorthatswhatIam
```

One way to achieve this would be

```
"I'm the janitor, that's what I am!".gsub(" ", "").gsub(",","").gsub("'","").gsub("!","")
```

This works but it looks pretty clumsy. Another way to handle this task would probably be regular expressions. Is there a more "ruby"-way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "")` should remove everything that is not English alphabet.

Comment: I think you meant `/[^a-zA-Z]/`..

Comment: @AdamEberlin: I'm not sure about the ruby syntax since I don't use it. I'm only sure about the regex.

Comment: What do you consider to be a "character"? Would `µ` or `é` be a character? How about `字`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. After rechecking the documentation for gsub, I realized that it is possible to use regular expressions within it, not just single characters. I used str.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "") to process my string as it is sufficient for the task required in my homework.

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex instead of strings in `.gsub`, like `/\W/`, which matches non-word chars:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194 :001 > x = "I'm the janitor, that's what I am!"
 => "I'm the janitor, that's what I am!" 

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :002 > x.gsub(/\W/, '')
 => "ImthejanitorthatswhatIam"
```

As @nhahtdh pointed out, this includes numbers and underscores.

A regex which can accomplish this task without doing so is `/[^a-zA-Z]/`:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194 :001 > x = "I'm the janitor, that's what I am!"
 => "I'm the janitor, that's what I am!" 

ruby-1.9.3-p194 :003 > x.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/, "")
 => "ImthejanitorthatswhatIam"
```

Comment: I don't know what the OP wants, but `\W` is everything except English alphabet upper and lower, **0-9 digits** and **underscore**.